# chcon: cannot access (file): No such file or directory

Tags: linux, command-line, filenames

I'm taking a Linux course and I have no idea on how to get past this annoying error:

```
chcon: cannot access path: No such file or directory
```

But before that we had to define our virtual host

Perhaps maybe that's where the error resides, but I'm not sure because I've checked and retyped everything but still get the error after replacing everything with my FQDN.

Then he asked us to "create the actual directories we just defined for our Virtual Hosts".

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo mkdir default
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t beta.lt.unt.edu/ beta-vh.lt.unt.edu/
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

[

This is where my brain starts hurting because instead I get this error.

```
chcon: cannot access ‛elm.lt.unt.edu/elm-vh.lt.unt.edu/’: No such file or directory
```

Why is it saying that? I asked the instructor but it was no help.

Comment: trying to change the context of a directory that doesn't exist yet?  create it ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Thanks for contributing! But please, don't post images of text ([read this for reasons why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. As [steve (vaguely) said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/513604/80216#comment949834_513604),
   you appear to be trying to change the context
   of directories that don’t exist yet. 
   You have showed us `mkdir default`;
   you need to create `elm.lt.unt.edu` and `elm-vh.lt.unt.edu` also.
2. It looks like you actually said

   ```
   sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t elm.lt.unt.edu/elm-vh.lt.unt.edu/
   ```

   when you should have said

   ```
   sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t elm.lt.unt.edu/ elm-vh.lt.unt.edu/
   ```

   (with a space between the two directory names).

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that I actually had to create it. Thank you so much I did mkdir elm.It.unt.edu/ then mkdir elm-vh.It.unt.edu on separate lines and it worked!

Comment: Well, I guess that’s what your instructor meant when he said, “create the actual directories we just defined for our Virtual Hosts”.